# How do a pass multliple returns from a function to a a structured variable in swift (OSX)

Tags: macos, struct, swift, return, func

I'm trying to take two return values from one function, and put them into a variable that has a defined structure.

I know I'm not doing it right because I'm getting an error.
What is the correct way to do this? - or am I barking up the wrong tree?

```
struct aWord {
    var letters: [Character] = []
    var word: String = ""
}

let myDictinary = ["cheese", "tree","pea","fleas","house"]

var chosenWord: aWord

func pickWord() -> (letters: Array<Character>, fullWord:String) {
    var x = UInt32(myDictinary.count - 1)
    var n = Int(arc4random_uniform(x))
    var chosen = myDictinary[n]
    var word : [Character] = []

    for letter in chosen {
        word.append(letter)

    }
    return (word, chosen)


}


chosenWord = pickWord()

println(chosenWord.word)
```

The error message I'm getting is for the line chosenWord = pickWord() :
(letters: Array, fullWord: String)' is not convertible to 'aWord'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chosenWord` is a struct, `pickWord` returns a tuple. You can't just store a tuple into space meant for a struct. Either declare `chosenWord` to be a tuple (with the appropriate types) or make `pickWord` return `aWord`.

Comment: Thanks Kevin - got that now!
I've tolde pickword() to return a aWord.